# How to apply ft_string_indexer on multiple columns with sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, sparklyr

I have multiple categorical columns and I want to apply the `ft_string_indexer` on them one by one but in one line of code. I don't need to convert the numbers back to string, so I tried the following:

1. `mutate_at`

```
cols <- c('col_1','col_2')
tbl_data <- spark_read_csv(...)
tbl_data %>%
  mutate_at(cols, ft_string_indexer)

Error in (function (x, input_col = NULL, output_col = NULL, handle_invalid = "error",  : 
  object 'col_1' not found
```

Somehow it doesn't seem to be able to recognize the column names.

2. `mutate` + `across`

```
cols <- c('col_1','col_2')
tbl_data <- spark_read_csv(...)
tbl_data %>%
  mutate(across(cols, ft_string_indexer))

  ERROR sparklyr:  (0) failed calling sql on 9: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'ft_string_indexer'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'...
```

In this approach it doesn't recognize `ft_string_indexer`.

Does anyone know what's the right way to do that? Thank you!

Edited:
package versions -
sparklyr: 1.5.1
dplyr: 1.0.5

Comment: @akrun I got exactly the same error (object <col name> not found) when applying `vars()` on the column names :(

Comment: then i guess the functions are not meant to be used in spark.  are you getting the same error with `mutate(col_1 = ft_string_indexer(col_1))`

Comment: @akrun you are right, this doesn't work for me either.. I thought it could work because I saw this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45678282/sparklyr-handing-categorical-variables) where `sdf_mutate(col = ft_string_indexer(col))` was used, and since `sdf_mutate` is deprecated I tried `mutate`

Comment: I have some issues in installing the sparklyr for testing